# Tabhost with Google map android api v2 is not showing google map it shows only title issues in fragmentActivity in tabhost

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, fragment-tab-host

I am new to android I want to implement Google map on Tabhost.I have three tabs,In third tab i want to implement google map Version 2.

All are working Fine except google map tab.It shows only title and marker on the title.It does not shows google map.

This is my Tabhost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layTab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btm_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >
            <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layTab"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is Tabhost.java class

```
 public class Tabhost extends Activity {
        TabHost tabHost;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabhost);
            Resources res = getResources();
            LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
            mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
            tabHost.setup(mlam );
          Intent intent;

            // Tab for Photos
            TabSpec list = tabHost.newTabSpec("list");
            list.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, MapList.class);
            list.setContent(listIntent);



            TabSpec account = tabHost.newTabSpec("account");
            account.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lock));
            Intent accountIntent = new Intent(this, FrontPage.class);
            account.setContent(accountIntent);



           TabSpec Map = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map");
            nearby.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nearby));
            Intent nearbyIntent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
          nearby.setContent(nearbyIntent);

            tabHost.addTab(list);
          tabHost.addTab(account);
          tabHost.addTab(Map);
          tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tab working", 1000).show();
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

    }

this is my Map_activity

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener {
GoogleMap Gmap;
Marker blueMarker,redMarker;
   Location location;

       LocationManager service;

       String provider;
       Criteria criteria;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.next);

    /*  
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);*/

       /* int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available         
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {

        */

        // gps = new GPSTracker(Next.this);

            Gmap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();
            Gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            Gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                Gmap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
             Gmap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
          Gmap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)       
                      Next.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                       NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                           NetworkInfo mobileInfo = 
                            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                           if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected()) {

                               service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                                criteria = new Criteria();
                                provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                            location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                               latitude= location.getLatitude();
                               longitude=location.getLongitude();

                               Gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                               Gmap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
                               final LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                             blueMarker= Gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                             .position(myLocation)
                             .title("my Position")
                             .snippet("This is you")
                             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                 .fromResource(R.drawable.mark_blue)));



                          Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 10));
}
}
```

This is my Map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<fragment
       android:id="@+id/map1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Any one solve this issue

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (google maps v2 showed only a grey grid in a tab, but if I load it as a main activity without tabs than it works).
Then I added **mMapFragment.onResume()** and now it works in a tab! Try this:

```
mMapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
mMapFragment.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
```

I've found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16960527/185493

Comment: A good idea. I add "((CustomSupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fm_map)).onResume();" in onResume of fragment and it works for me. Thanks!